# I want to use the 'if ~ else if' function to perform some instructions if the first data is character and to perform other if they are numbers

Tags: sas

In SAS, I want to use the 'if ~ else if' function to perform some instructions if the first data is character and to perform other instructions if they are numbers.

I tried to use 'if ~ else if' statement but I do not know how to specify the conditional statement.

---

In this code,

```
data pr1;
input ~~~~
put profname$ course;
cards;
LEE 22
15 PARK
;
run;
```

I want to show this.

```
profname　course
　LEE　　　　22  
　PARK　　　 15
```

What can I put in '~~~' ??

Comment: You can definitely treat it in SAS (and Chris Long provides a nice solution below), but it would be wise to fix the order in the source system where the problem originates.

Answer (score 1):

There may be some clever INPUT statement magic you could do here, but I think the easiest, clearest solution would be to read in both columns as character data and then test them to see which column has which data:

```
data pr1 (keep = profname course);

  * Declare PROFNAME as character and COURSE as numeric;
  length profname $ 20 course 8;

  * Read in two columns of data;
  input col1 $ col2 $

  if input(col1, ??best.) = . then do;
    * If COL1 cannot be converted to a number, assume it is a name;
    profname = col1;
    course = input(col2, ??best.);
  end; else do;
    * Otherwise assume COL2 is the name;
    profname = col2;
    course = input(col1, ??best.);
  end;

  cards;
LEE 22
15 PARK
  ;
run;
```

The `??` modifiers in the `INPUT()` function suppress the usual warnings when a value can't be processed.